# JDA java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/exc/InputCoercionException

Tags: java, discord-jda

So, i have a problem with Discord-JDA Wrapper. I trying to login my discord bot. But when i launch it, i am getting a exception:

```
[JDA RateLimit-Worker 1] ERROR RateLimiter - Encountered exception trying to execute request
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/exc/InputCoercionException
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.createMapDeserializer(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:1376)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:384)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:349)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:476)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:4389)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4198)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3234)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.utils.data.DataObject.fromJson(DataObject.java:175)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.Response.parseBody(Response.java:204)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.Response.parseBody(Response.java:182)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.Response.get(Response.java:124)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.Response.getObject(Response.java:105)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.utils.SessionControllerAdapter.lambda$getGateway$0(SessionControllerAdapter.java:86)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.RestActionImpl.handleSuccess(RestActionImpl.java:268)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.RestActionImpl.handleResponse(RestActionImpl.java:258)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.Request.handleResponse(Request.java:259)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.Requester.execute(Requester.java:235)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.Requester.execute(Requester.java:139)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.Requester.execute(Requester.java:122)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.ratelimit.BotRateLimiter$Bucket.run(BotRateLimiter.java:461)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.exc.InputCoercionException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 29 more
```

I really don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me?

Btw. Token is correct

oh, i forgot to post code:

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

public class DiscordLog {
    public static void sendLog() throws LoginException {
        JDA jda = new JDABuilder("here is my token").build();


    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: "[JDA RateLimit-Worker 1] ERROR RateLimiter - Encountered exception trying to execute request"

Comment: That is not an exception, its a message telling you there is an exception.

Comment: @Minn oh, sorry. Here is full stacktrace: https://hastebin.com/asevebolef.cs

Answer (score 0):

You are using an incorrect jackson dependency. I recommend you check your build setup, whether it is maven or gradle, for dependency conflicts. Jackson requires all components to be on the same version to function properly.

Make sure you include all of JDA's dependencies and make sure all your other dependencies are up-to-date.

If you don't use maven or gradle then I recommend you start using gradle. The JDA wiki provides [setup guides](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/2%29-Setup) explaining how to setup a project properly with gradle.
You can debug your dependencies with both maven and gradle:

### Gradle

```
./gradlew dependencies
```

You can use [resolution strategies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html) to enforce specific versions of the jackson components. JDA uses **2.10.1**.

### Maven

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

You can force versions by putting them directly into your dependency list at the top.